# Searching a String[][] grid for an element and immediate surrounding ones

Tags: java, search, multidimensional-array

This is a representation of my grid-

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 E 0 P 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 E 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 P 0
0 0 P 0 0 0
```

My question is that if I select a certain point, how do I search the immediate area (8 elements) for anything that is either E or P?

What I have currently for the search function-

```
if (eventMap[x][y].equals("*")) {
  System.out.println("Nothing is there.");
if (eventMap[x][y].equals("E")) {
  System.out.println("There is a ship trail at that location.");
} else if (eventMap[x][y].equals("P"))
  System.out.println("There is a planet at that location.");
```

this is my first question asked here, so sorry if anything is ugly looking.

Comment: ...By selecting those points?  Not sure what else you're looking for, honestly.

Comment: By selecting any coordinate in that grid.

Comment: You do it by writing some code. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Do not put code in a comment. **Edit** the question and add the code there, to clarify the question.

Comment: Gut reaction:  why are you comparing `"P"` with `==`?  Then I look at the rest of your code and realize you're doing String comparison the *right* way there...

Comment: i was just retyping the code and by accident did == instead of .equals thanks for that check

Comment: About the right way to compare string, the best practice is to always put the constants on the left side of the equals, so that you are safe against null cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you are at position `[i][j]`, the immediate surrounding ones are `[i-1][j-1]`, `[i-1][j]`, `[i-1][j+1]`, `[i][j-1]`, `[i][j+1]`, `[i+1][j-1]`, `[i+1][j]` and `[i+1][j+1]`. If you want to avoid checking each one by one, just go though the array with a double loop with k going from i-1 to i+1 and l going from j-1 to j+1 and get `[k][l]` and if needed add an if to skip the case `k == i && l == j` to remove the middle one. Obviously you also have to handle edge cases.

Comment: I have tried that using more if-else statements but they just seem to just not work, maybe I'm just messily adding code or something

Comment: Your outer code going through the matrix should by done with two for loops, then inside you need to check the upper and lower limit for k and l (like kmin = i - 1 < 0 ? 0 : i - 1; kmax = i + 1 > array.length - 1 : array.length - 1 : i + 1) and then you can use loops to search for your specifics cases and do something when you find them.